# Different output in MSBuild vs Visual Studio Build

Tags: msbuild

I have an application and a Custom configuration that i created for my project requirement, which copy settings from x86.

Now if I build the application from Visual Studio, it is generating the output in the "Custom Configuration" folder under Bin directory. But if i use MSbuild from the command line then the output will be in x86/Custom Configuration folder.

I am trying to understand the difference.

Actually msbuild is using x86 platform, instead of Active. How should i change it.

While using MSBuild from the command line, i just want to pass configuration as parameter and not the platform, i believe it should automatically picked the right platform associated with that configuration.As per Specified in Project Properties and Build Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select a custom platform and configuration using the [`/property` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) on the msbuild command line:

```
msbuild /p:"Platform=MyPlatform" /p:"Configuration=CustomConfig"
```

Comment: Yeah That works, but i just want to pass the configuration parameter as i believe, each configuration is associated with platform. But it is not working this way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question to explain in a little more detail what you'd like and why my current solution doesn't work for you.

Comment: i've updated by question, will you please take a look at it and for the record, your answer works just fine for me, i just want it to do little better.

Comment: Are you passing your solution file or a project file to msbuild?

Comment: I am in the folder where project file resides and not the solution file, i am not passing any thing, by default i believe it'll pick project file.